# ERROR: Subquery evaluated to more than one row in Proc SQL

Tags: sql, proc-sql

I have a table -

```
Name    Job Group     Profession
John    Engineering    Yes
Shawn   Biology        Yes
Meg     Biology        No
Mike    Engineering    Yes   
Meg     Biology        Yes
John    Engineering    Yes
Mike    Biology        Yes
John    Engineering    Yes
Meg     Biology        Yes
```

I want to count Profession(either Yes or No) for same names corresponding to Job group. So the output I want is -

Output

```
Name   Engineering  Biology 
John      2            1
Mike      1            1
Shawn                  1
Meg                    2
```

I tried with this code but no luck -

```
CREATE TABLE Profile AS   
SELECT P.Name
        ,sum(P.Profession = "Yes") as Engineering_Yes
        ,sum(P.Profession = "Yes") as Engineering_No
        ,sum(P.Profession = "No") as Biology_Yes
        ,sum(P.Profession = "No") as Biology_Yes            
FROM Profile P
```

I tried to add Job Group column using union select but no luck

I am new to Proc SQL.I tried to search same example but cannot find it for Proc SQL. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select P.Name,
    count(case when "Job Group" = 'Engineering' then 1 end) as Engineering,
    count(case when "Job Group" = 'Biology' then 1 end) as Biology,
from Profile P
where Profession = 'Yes'
group by Name
```

Comment: I don't think proc sql has  count function

Comment: I think you sample output is wrong. John should show values (3, 0) by my count and Meg should be a (0, 3). I don't follow whether the Yes/No column is even pertinent to the question. Try removing the `where` clause to see if that gets you closer.

Comment: Though I have a question - what if I have to combine count(Y/N) for group Engineering, Biology and let say another - Sales. I tried - case when "Job Group" = 'Engineering' and case when "Job Group" = 'Biology' and case when "Job Group" = 'Sales'' but it just gave empty values in the column

Comment: Try `OR` rather than `AND`. Look into `IN` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do use `GROUP BY`:

```
CREATE TABLE Profile AS   
    SELECT P.Name,
           sum(case when P.Job_Group = 'Engineering' and P.Profession = 'Yes' and  then 1 else 0 end) as Engineering_Yes,
           sum(case when P.Job_Group = 'Engineering' and P.Profession = 'No' then 1 else 0 end) as Engineering_No,
           sum(case when P.Job_Group = 'Biology' and P.Profession = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as Biology_Yes,
           sum(case when P.Job_Group = 'Biology' and P.Profession = 'No' then 1 else 0 end) as Biology_No           
    FROM Profile P
    GROUP BY P.Name;
```

Comment: either get 0 or 1 in Engineering or Biology column. I want the sum of Yes or No and there is error in code. It runs when I remove sum or appy sum t profession(sum(P.Profession)